# Can animate div via console but not from JS file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an overlay which contains a div and a couple of other elements.

I'm trying to get the div to scale up with a transition upon opening the overlay.

**HTML**

```
    <div id="item-overlay" class="overlay">
        <div id="item-panel" class="overlay-panel">
            <div class="overlay-panel-top">
                <h1 id="item-panel-title" class="main-panel-txt">Item</h1>
                <img class="close" src="images/close.png" alt="" onclick="closeOverlay()">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.overlay{
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 2; 
}

#item-panel{
    width: 0%;
    height: 75%;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 25px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
```

**JS**

```
var itmOverlay = document.getElementById("item-overlay");
var itemPanel = document.getElementById("item-panel")

function itemOverlay(){
    itmOverlay.style.display = "flex";
    itemPanel.style.width = "50%";
}

function closeOverlay(){
    itmOverlay.style.display = "none";
    itemPanel.style.width = "0%";
}
```

This doesn't work, the of div just appears at full-size when opening the overlay. However, I can past the code above into the console and the transition will work.

I'm really not sure what's going on here.

Comment: Hi there, this seems to be some timing issue. Check if the item elements are loaded before or after the script is executed. Debugging through the code line by line to check when and if it is executed will help. Check out your browser devtools to do that.

Comment: The element starts at 0% width, so the function is being executed otherwise the element wouldn't appear at the correct size. I managed to get it working a different way but I'm curious as to why the method above doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure why the code above doesn't work, but I managed to get the desired effect by changing the width in a separate function that's called after the overlay is enabled.

```
function itemOverlay(){
    itmOverlay.style.display = "flex";
    setTimeout(openOverlayTimer, 10);
}



function openOverlayTimer(){
    itemPanel.style.width = "50%";
}
```